# Подпись приложения сертификатом другой компании

Tags: ios, xcode

Нужно подписать приложение для другой компании.
Эта компания дала мне только .mobileprovision и добавила мой эппл аккаунт как мембера.

Бандл выставил их.

XCode выдает ошибку, скрин ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопросы:**

1. В чем может быть причина ?
2. Как правильно подписывать приложение для другой компании, когда тебя добавили как мембера ?

Comment: Вам надо загрузить их приложение в аппсотр?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, спасибо за отклик. Неа. Ин-Хаус. Точнее мне просто нужно получить .ipa файл с ихнем Бандл Ид

Comment: вам нужен сертификат. заходите на developer.apple.com и делайте себе какой надо - доступ у вас есть

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, когда я зашел под тем акк, что они добавили к себе в мемебры - у меня неактивна кнопка скачивания и добавления сертификатов(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попросите у них экспорт сертификата обязательно с ключом.

делать его примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хорошо, попробую)

Comment: попробуйте, это должно помочь. На крайний случай просто отзовите и переделайте на себя все сертификаты и обновите профайл, на уже зарелиженных приложениях это никак не скажется

Comment: почему бы и нет ) skype: igor_dnp

Answer (score 0):

Если твой аккаунт добавлен к другому, то ты можешь добавить свой акк в XCode. XCode сам запросит dev certificate и сделает недостающие провижены.
Если будут проблемы - нажимай Resolve или Fix на алерте (увидишь при компиляции).

Только не забудь правильно выставить Team на вкладке General.